# GridView : Freezing First Columns and Freezing Column's Headers

Tags: gridview, freeze

Hi any body can tell  how to freeze gridview Header and some two colums based on axis there fore a gridview should have both vertical and horizontal scroll so that when scrolling vertically need to freez the header and when scrolling horizontally freeze  the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Hay I have found an effective way to freez grid header. Ultimately the grid is rendered as table. So follow this fiddle that I have developed http://jsfiddle.net/jogendra09/BCrXZ/65/. It's an unique way to freez header. I have developed it for chrome, but can be modified to maintain cross-browser compatibility . And yes, It uses jQuery.