# Freezing Header and First Column of a Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, header

I Got a problem in Designing a gridview with Header and First column are frozen. I searched all over net, i found the solutions with individual feature but could not find the actual solution where Header and first column are freezed.

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1120278.aspx
- [GridView : Freezing First Columns and Freezing Column's Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732824/gridview-freezing-first-columns-and-freezing-columns-headers)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551576/freezing-first-column-and-header-of-an-gridview

Comment: This one works for `ASP.NET` `DataGrid` hope that may help. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13126/An-ASP-NET-DataGrid-Custom-Control-to-Freeze-Heade

Comment: In the first link there is property in style sheet property"left: expression(document.getElementById("div-datagrid").scrollLeft-2);" which is not supporting,even i ignore the warning i could not get it worked,,,till now i freezed Header using CSS , and first column but I cud not see first column's header and first column is overlapping vertically on the Gridview.

Comment: I am new here..sorry if my way of approaching is bit weird...how can i add my screen shots here??? It will be easy in understanding my problem